# counter loop in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

So I've got an Excel workbook with multiple worksheets. Each worksheet is the same template. And cells B3 - B39, C3 - C39, and D3 - D39 will contain 1 of 3 values. 1, .5, or no value at all (completely blank). Now each worksheet isn't exactly the same (some will go to B/C/D45 instead of just B/C/D39). I'm trying to have another cell show how many of those cells contain a 1, and another cell show how many contain a .5. Yeah I could manually do it, but I'm trying to get this as automated as possible.

Comment: Look at the COUNTIF worksheet function.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Such a simple solution as well... Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As @Variatus has suggested, you could just use the COUNTIF worksheet function, but if you wanted to do this with VBA, what you need to do is:

## Method

1. Identify the last row
2. Build the range
3. Count how many of the cells in this range contain `1`
4. Count how many of the cells in this range contain `.5`
5. Do something with these counts

## Code

```
Sub CountTheSheets()

    Const Value10 As Double = 1, Value05 As Double = 0.5 ' these are what we're comparing cell values against

    Dim Count10 As Long, Count05 As Long ' these are our 1 and .5 counts respectively
    Dim lastRow As Long, lastRowTemp As Long, maxRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cel As Range

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets ' iterate over all worksheets

        lastRow = 0 ' reset the last row for this worksheet
        Count10 = 0 ' reset the 1 count for this worksheet
        Count05 = 0 ' reset the .5 count for this worksheet

        With ws

            maxRow = .Rows.Count ' this is the absolute bottom row in a worksheet

            ' get last row of column B, by going to the bottom of the worksheet in that column, then using End and going up to find the last cell
            lastRowTemp = .Cells(maxRow, "B").End(xlUp).Row
            If lastRowTemp > lastRow Then lastRow = lastRowTemp

            ' get last row of column C; if larger than the previous, store in lastRow that row number instead
            lastRowTemp = .Cells(maxRow, "C").End(xlUp).Row
            If lastRowTemp > lastRow Then lastRow = lastRowTemp

            ' get last row of column D; if larger than the previous, store in lastRow that row number instead
            lastRowTemp = .Cells(maxRow, "D").End(xlUp).Row
            If lastRowTemp > lastRow Then lastRow = lastRowTemp

            ' build the range using lastRow, and iterate through the cells in that range, counting the matching values
            For Each cel In .Range("B3:D" & lastRow)

                If cel.Value = Value10 Then
                    Count10 = Count10 + 1
                ElseIf cel.Value = Value05 Then
                    Count05 = Count05 + 1
                End If

            Next cel

            ' do something with these counts
            Debug.Print .Name, Count10, Count05

        End With
    Next ws

End Sub
```